# Creating semi-random planting designs in R

Tags: r, poisson-distribution, spatial

I want to use R to create 'random' planting plans - drawing plants manually (CAD) is neither random nor efficient - my aim is a list of plants, within an irregular region, (up to 10,000 plants) with their respective numbers and positions.

This would use points (trees) of different diameters, with a coverage ratio for each tree, and a predefined level of how the points attract or repel as in attached image. [image]True randomness would not occur as the points would not be truly independent.

The maximum plant coverage (range 50% to 100%) would probably be a circle-packing problem, but where packing is random - so maximum number of circles that fit the region while being as random as possible, the result of this would be 100% coverage. My (unstatistical) mind tells me this number could inform the number of circles for subsequent runs of the model for coverages <100%.

Before I take this further is this do-able in R, and if so what steps should I take?

Comment: Could you clarify--preferably in a quantitative way--how "repulsion" is supposed to work?  Also, the intensity of planting can make a difference in algorithms depending on whether the plant polygons cover a negligible proportion of the planting area or a large part of it.  Could you give some guidance in that regard?  Finally, do you really want a completely at random--"Poisson"--distribution or do you need the plantings to cluster (with each other or around other features like the boundaries)?

Comment: I'm struggling with one thing you wrote: in what sense would you say that a design like (c) has covered 100% of a region, given there are substantial gaps between the disks?

Comment: What I think is needed is a **kernel function** to 'push' points a defined distance from circle centres (probably a mark in each species' record). Planting coverage will be 70-100% - which the 'kernel function' would provide by pushing or pulling - and the degree of this would raise or lower the total point number. Plant cov. of 100% would mean max. number of circles touching - real plants would tend to grow into the interstices left between the circles.  It's probably more accurate to call it _maximum circle packing for a given coverage_.  At this point a 'Poisson' distribution would be fine.

Comment: What can you say about the disk diameters? Are they prespecified or random, too?  For instance, do they correspond to typical diameters of plants of different species and you will stipulate what proportion of all plants is each species?

Comment: There will be 8 discs representing different plant sizes; 1.0metres dia., 1.5, 2.0, 3.0, 5.0, 7.5, 10.0 and 15.0m. and yes I would need to specify what proportion of the region would be allocated to each species.

Comment: I've found this [link] (http://www.r-bloggers.com/circle-packing-with-r/) which is closer to what I want, not there yet though.

Comment: You found a good approach: the natural alternative of sequentially placing disks randomly into the complement of all previous disks becomes impracticable when the disks almost fill the entire region.

Comment: Thanks whuber - I'm going to work on some of the ideas here and come back when i know more